# Inverting animation direction

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to invert animation in HTML/CSS/jQuery.
I was trying to do it with flexbox, but I can't.

Now it's animating from right to left, but I want to do it from left to right. Also content 1 should be visible at the beginning, and then after animation finished content 2 should be visible.

HTML:

```
<div id="slides">
  <div class="cont1 activeTab">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div class="cont2">
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>xxx</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slides{  
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#cf5;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#slides div{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-4px;
  white-space:normal;
  vertical-align:top;
  *display:inline;
  background:#eee;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
#slides .cont1 {
  background: red;
}
#slides .cont2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  var slideW = $('#slides').width();
  $('button').click(function( e ){
    var el = $(this),
        state = el.data('animState');
    if(state == 'busy') {
       return false;
    } 
    el.data('animState', 'busy');
    if ($('.cont1').hasClass('activeTab')) {
      $('#slides').animate({scrollLeft: slideW }, 600, function(){
        $('.cont1').removeClass('activeTab');
        $('.cont2').addClass('activeTab');
        el.data('animState', 'complete'); 
      });
    } else {
      $('#slides').animate({scrollLeft: 0 }, 600, function(){
        $('.cont1').addClass('activeTab');
        $('.cont2').removeClass('activeTab');
        el.data('animState', 'complete');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk8emurf/1/)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` like this:

```
#slides{  
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#cf5;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
#slides div{
  flex:0 0 100%;
  position:relative;
  background:#eee;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

And then on your JS just change the `scrollLeft` value to be animated first to `0` and after to `slideW`.

#### [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk8emurf/3/)